# Image thumbnail view/editor in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, thumbnails

Could anyone suggest to me how to load multiple images in one tab and after clicking on a particular image it should open in another tab for image processing?

here is the part of my code. here instead if drawing image i actually required to open the load the the images and on selecting particular image it should open to other tab. please suggest me how is it done using jlist or by any other means..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SwindDesign {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Split Pain");
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    //panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(new PicturePanel());

   JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();

     jtp.addTab("Set Image", panel);
      jtp.addTab("Compare Image", new JButton());
      frame.add(jtp);

    }
}
class PicturePanel extends JPanel {

File folder = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
ImageIcon[] img ;
JComponent lblimg;
JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
private BufferedImage[] b = new BufferedImage[10];

public PicturePanel() throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("chek panth"+listOfFiles[i].getName().toString());
        b[i] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/" + listOfFiles[i].getName().toString()));
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    int k = 10;
    for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length - 1; j++) {
        g2.drawImage(b[j], k, 0, 100, 100, null);
        k = k + 75;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i could able load multiple images in a thumbnail using imageicon and jlable but by doing this i was not able to get what i need.

I am developing a Image processing application show need show multiple images of folder in thumbnail and on click it should be open  in other tab to process on it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> could anyone suggest me how to load multiple..

Use a loop.

> ..images..

Use `ImageIO.read(File/URL/InputStream)`

> in on tab..

Add a `JPanel` to the tab with a suitable layout, E.G. `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout`. Put the image in an undecorated `JButton` and add it to the panel.

> ..and after clicking on a particular image..

Add an `ActionListener` to the button.

> ..it should open inn a other tab for image processing.

`JTabbedPane.addTab("image name", imageEditorComponent)`

Comment: hello
now i have another small issue. I need To click on two image Simultaneously for the compare purpose i mean those both clicked  images should open in another tab to compare
could you please suggest me the way how to over come this?

Comment: Use a `JList` to show the original images.  Add a `ListSelectionListener` to the list.  Add buttons below the list (Edit, Compare etc.) possibly in a `JToolBar`.  On receiving a `ListSelectionEvent` in the listener, get `int numSelect = list.getSelectedIndices()`.  If `numSelect==2`, enable both Edit and Compare.  If the number is 0, disable both.  If one, only enable Edit.

Comment: thanks but as i am new to java development i have never use JList
like i have used jlist one or twice but never for showing multiple images. so please give me hint that how could i show multiple images using JList?

Comment: Why not ask on a new question and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt?

Comment: Andrew please u show me the way to show the image using jlist?

Comment: Please ask a new question and post an SSCCE of your best attempt.

Comment: hello Andrew i had posted my attempt above please refer it when you get time and please suggest me what change i have to made to load and show the images using jlist?
thanks

Comment: Which part are you having a *specific* problem with?  Finding which files are images?  Creating a `JList`?  Adding the list to the parent container?  Dumping code to the question that shows no apparent attempt to do any of those things, or ask a specific question, is not very encouraging for me to help.

Comment: Creating a JList with images and Adding the list to the parent container to show the thumbnail view of images